# I get how to install Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu from ppa. But how do I update them later when I need to?

Tags: nvidia, ppa, update-alternatives

As an owner of a 2080.  This is something I'm going to need to know how to do.

Comment: If the PPA is maintained properly (by nvidia), the normal update & upgrade method, that works for all program packages will work also for your driver, that you have installed via the PPA. I use the command line `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: It is not maintained by nvidia, but it is being updated by someone.

Answer (score 1):

Once a PPA is added to your source list.  The packages you install from it will be upgrade as needed.  You should be notified when new update is available if you don't install a specific version.